# Why same dll exposes different classes in C# and .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am using a third party .Net dll in my code and when I add a reference to this dll from a VB.Net application it shows different classes in intellisense and object browser than when I use it in a C# project. Why is there this difference?

**Edit**

If designer intended it that way I'd like to know how to do it in my own dlls.

Comment: what do you mean by different? Does c# show class A,B,C and vb.net shows D,E,F? OR is it that vb.net shows less number of classes than c#?

Comment: @shahkalpesh 
The classes shown in VB.Net projects are a subset of that shown in C# projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics, it is hard to say.  Some possibilities that come to mind are:

- The designer made it that way on purpose
- Parts of the library are not CLR compliant, and therefore not visible by languages other than the one it was written in.

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET provides the option to "hide advanced members". Perhaps it's the "advanced" members you're not seeing.

Comment: That could be the case, if the OP answers what I have asked.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember here is that intellisense is an approximation of what's allowed and legal in the program.  It's goal is to be very close to true but often isn't.  There are several reasons why a particular type may or may not show up in intellisense but does in C#

- One of the 2 projects may be friends with the target assembly
- Intellisense filters may exist on the documentation files which hide them from intellisense
- Attribute filters on the type
- Certain classes may get hidden due to case only differences in the name

Given that it also doesn't show up in the object browser, my guess is that the class has either intellisense or attribute filters that cause it to be hidden for VB.Net.

Comment: Forget friend assemblies as it's third party dll.